How do I convert to the Jewish. faith?
A little background about me: I was born and raised in an incredibly secular background, but my grandparents were Christian, so when I turned eighteen years old I myself decided to become a Christian, but for the past three years I have had this weird feeling that Christianity is wrong and that Christ is not the messiah, feeling a very strong pull towards Judaism, now I want to convert to the Jewish faith and wondered how would I became a Jew? Could I even convert if I haven't got any Jewish family?

Yes, you can convert, but not online.  You must contact a rabbi and discuss the matter with him.  Good luck!

Yes, of course you can convert! It's not necessarily easy. See this question for instructions: Is it possible for a Gentile to convert to Judaism?

Note this question is guaranteed to be closed for being duplicate as well as a personal request (which Mi Yodeya doesn't cater for), so please do not take that the wrong way - it's just site policy, and nothing to do with your question or situation personally/specifically
